# Derived class' method not found via dereferencing boost::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, shared-ptr

We have:

- base class `Base`;
- derived class `Derived`.

Declaration:

```
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
  Derived();  // ctor
  ~Derived(); // dtor
  void MakeSomething();
private:
  // some private stuff
}
```

Now we go to our main. This works fine:

```
// ...
Derived derived;
derived.MakeSomething();
// ...
```

On the contrary, this doesn't work:

```
// ...
boost::shared_ptr< Base > derived(new Derived);
derived->MakeSomething();
// ...
```

Compiler says:

> Error: class "Base" has no member "MakeSomething"

I know it hasn't, in fact I want to call `Derived`'s method! What am I missing with inheritance and pointers?

Additional issues:

- I cannot declare `MakeSomething()` virtual in `Base`, because `Base` belongs to a third-party's library which I can just inherit from;
- I have other classes and methods which require me to pass `boost::shared_ptr< Base >`, I cannot go straight with a `boost::shared_ptr< Derived >`;
- ...static casting should be avoided?

Comment: Class `Base` should declare `virtual void MakeSomething() = 0;` (and a virtual destructor as well)

Comment: ...so use `boost::static_pointer_cast<Derived>(derived)->MakeSomething();`

Comment: If you want to call a `Derived` method, get a pointer to `Derived`.

Comment: ... so, just use `boost::shared_ptr<Derived>` from the very beginning and pass it around when `boost::shared_ptr<Base>` is required?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Please don't advise newcomers to use casts.

Comment: @LisaAnn `boost::shared_ptr<Derived>` is implicitly convertible to `boost::shared_ptr<Base>`. you can use the former from the very beginning

Comment: I give it a try, wait for me :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use:

```
boost::shared_ptr< Base > derived = ...;
```

you can only access functions that are declared in `Base` through `derived`. The simplest analogy is to use raw pointers.

```
Base* ptr = new Derived;
```

Even though `ptr` points to a `Derived`, you cannot access member functions of `Derived` through the pointer.

Your choices are (that I can think of):

1. Define `virtual` member functions in `Base`,
2. Create a pointer to `Derived`, or
3. Use `dynamic_cast` appropriately to get a pointer to `Derived`.

Comment: This is why we have pure virtual functions and _interfaces_. Covered in any good C++ book.

Comment: I don't know how pure virtual functions and interfaces can help me when I cannot amend base classes, never found such a case in my C++ books for beginners. Sorry.

Comment: Ugh thank you so much for this, I was banging my head all morning on this.